# Which to use, WebClient.OpenRead, OpenReadAsync or OpenReadTaskAsync

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm trying to understand the differences among [`WebClient.OpenRead`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openread?view=netcore-2.0), [`WebClient.OpenReadAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadasync?view=netcore-2.0) and [`WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadtaskasync?view=netcore-2.0).

It looks like these have differences regarding blocking a thread, but I don't understand it well.
Could you please explain the differences? It would be great if you could give me some example (examples don't have to be sample code, but would be great if you could provide)

Comment: It can take a while to connect to the web server, OpenRead() may hang your user interface for a while.  So they provided OpenReadAsync() as an alternative.  But it is not so easy to use correctly.  In .NET 4.5 they added support for async/await.  That made OpenReadTaskAsync() useful, now it is easier to use since you can simply await the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the difference is in thread blocking behavior. First one ([OpenRead()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openread?view=netcore-2.0)) is thread blocking operation, other two - not. For example, let assume, that your network latency to reach *google.com* is 300ms. When you do `var stream = webClient.OpenRead(@"https://www.google.com");` your application is *"paused"* for this 300ms, so code next to this line is not executed until your `webClient` return a stream to `stream` variable. This is calling *Thread blocking*.

When you do this in UI-thread (in example: in a button click handler) - your application become freezing and not responding to user actions. This is **bad** user experience, so never-ever call a thread blocking stuff in your UI. Here is example for console application:

```
var address = @"https://www.google.com/";

Console.WriteLine($"Opening stream from {address}");
using (var stream = webClient.OpenRead(address)) // this will block for 300ms
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stream is open!");
    // some other code
}
```

Second method ([OpenReadAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadasync?view=netcore-2.0)) is **asynchronous** and return nothing immediately after a call, so your thread is not blocked. After awhile (300ms) [OpenReadCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadcompleted?view=netcore-2.0) event will be raised by your `webClient` and all attached listeners will handle opened stream one-by-one. Here is an example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private WebClient _client = new WebClient();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
        _client.OpenReadCompleted += OpenReadCompletedHandler;
    }

    private void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _client.OpenReadAsync(@"https://www.google.com/");
    }

    private void OpenReadCompletedHandler(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // this event will be raiesed 300ms after 'Button' click
        var stream = e.Result; // <- here is your stream
        // some other code
    }
}
```

The last one ([OpenReadTaskAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.openreadtaskasync?view=netcore-2.0)) is all about [TPL (Task Parallel Library)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) and **async**/**await** keywords. It runs all stuff in a `Task` which is returned by this method. Here is an example:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private WebClient _client = new WebClient();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponents();
    }

    private async void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // after 'await' keyword, execution will be returned from this method immediately
        // meanwhile, actual acquiring of 'stream' is running in a background thread
        using (var stream = await _client.OpenReadTaskAsync(@"https://www.google.com/"))
        {
            // after 300ms, this code will be continued in UI thread
            // result will be automaticly unpacked to 'stream' variable

            // some other code
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest `WebClient` is more or less obsolete now, `HttpClient` is more appropriate for anything targeting .NET framework 4.5+ or .NET core.  Just watch out that the latter does not automatically throw exceptions on HTTP error codes (400+).

Comment: this should be a comment